# DASK can't recognize workers on EMR

Tags: python, dask, amazon-emr, dask-distributed, joblib

I have a script to parallelize a web scraping job. We want to use joblib and dask for this. I created a cluster on EMR but I don't know how I will work with dask on EMR.

When I scale it, it seems it has 4gb memory but actually I have 16gb memory for each. I want to scale it to use all instances and their capacities. how I can do that and how I can scale the DASK Client programmatically to scale itself for the maximum capacity. (e.g today I am using 3 instances but sometimes it will be 10-20-30 etc. when we start the cluster)

EMR Cluster:

1 Master - m5.xlarge 4 vCore, 16 GiB memory

2 Core - m5.xlarge 4 vCore, 16 GiB memory

```
from dask_yarn import YarnCluster
from dask.distributed import Client

cluster = YarnCluster()
client = Client(cluster)

client.scale(2)

print(client)

[OUT] <Client: 'tcp://172.31.27.208:33307' processes=2 threads=2, memory=4.29 GB>

with joblib.parallel_backend('dask'):
    parse_results: List[Dict[str, Any]] = Parallel()(delayed(parse)(i) for i in range(min_id, max_id))
```

Comment: I have the same question. It seems the AWS API allows you to get the EC2 instance ids and types associated with your cluster so assuming you can programatically figure out your own cluster id you could determine # of available cores and memory. I'm going to be trying this, but it would be nice if there's a simpler approach. There's also the .adapt() function.